# Is a power series pointwise convergent in its interval of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, uniform-convergence

I know a power series is not necessarily uniformly convergent in its interval of convergence, but I was wondering whether it may be pointwise convergent in this interval? If this is false, I would be grateful if a counter example could be provided.

Comment: By definition, power series converge (pointwise) within their interval of convergence. (More precisely, one proves that the region where the series converges is an interval.)

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry in hindsight this was obvious!

Comment: Uniform convergence is a much stronger requirement than pointwise convergence. The result here is that the series converges uniformly on any compact subset of the (interior of the) interval of convergence.

Comment: I haven't learnt about compact spaces, but if a series has radius of convergence $R$, are you saying that for all $\alpha < R$ the series is uniformly convergent on $|x| < \alpha$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: (More exactly, while the set $(-\alpha,\alpha) $ is itself not compact, it is contained in a compact subset of $(-R,R) $, and any compact subset of $(-R,R)$ is contained in one such interval. The compact sets in $\mathbb R $ are the closed and bounded sets, the relevant examples in the setting of power series are just the closed intervals.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R $ be the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum a_nx^n $.

The convergence is uniform at any compact $[a,b]\subset ]-R,R [$

BUT

if $\sum a_nR^n $ and $\sum a_n (-R)^n $ are convergent then the convergence is uniform at $[-R,R] $.

Comment: Thank you Salahamam_Fatima.